# How can I connect to an X11 server via `ssh` and apply a scaling factor on the graphics?

Tags: ssh, x11

I want to connect to an X11 server using `ssh -X username@10.x.x.x`, and then start a program in the resulting X11 connection.

When I do this currently, the window start on the client computer, but the text is way way too small to read (like, 1-2mm tall). I assume the issue is that the application is very old, and I'm now using high-DPI monitors.

Is there a way I can scale the application up? Perhaps using Xephyr?

- The environment is with Linux Mint 22 (Cinnamon).
- The application is Cadence. It does not support font size adjustment, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The application is Cadence. It does not support fone size adjustment, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Just a nit-pick but the X11 server is the system displaying the output. The X11 client is the system on which the application is run.

Answer (score 0):

As described in
https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f/custom-ic-design/24143/default-font-size-for-virtuoso-visualization-analysis
you can adjust the `viva.axis` font attribute
in your `~/.cdsenv` config file.

Additional documentation details are available from the vendor.